# Convert HTML to XLSX with PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have this code, this basically create and save a HTML table, then using PHPexcel I tried to convert, but the XLSX is completely wrong and the HTML is OK, this is my first time using PHPExcel, I don't know if I'm doing something wrong.

```
<?php
session_start();
include('includes/connect.php');
$query = $_SESSION['query'];
$qry = $mysqli->query($query);
//echo $mysqli->error;

$str_html = "
<body>
    <table>
<tr>
  <th>
    Apellido
  </th>
  <th>
    Nombre
  </th>
  <th>
    E-Mail
  </th>
  <th>
    Tel&eacute;fono Celular
  </th>
  <th>
    CV
  </th>
  <th>
    Foto
  </th>";

$query1 = "SELECT * FROM ind_exp ORDER BY nombre ASC";
$qry1 = $mysqli->query($query1);
while($f1 = $qry1->fetch_assoc())
{
    $str_html = $str_html."
    <th>
    Experiencia en Industrias de: ".mb_convert_encoding($f1['nombre'],'utf-16','utf-8').
        '</th>';
}
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM proy_exp ORDER BY nombre ASC";
$qry2 = $mysqli->query($query2);
while($f2 = $qry2->fetch_assoc())
{
    $str_html = $str_html."<th>
    Experiencia en Proyectos de: ".mb_convert_encoding($f2['nombre'],'utf-16','utf-8').
        '</th>';
}
$query3 = "SELECT * FROM rol_exp ORDER BY nombre ASC";
$qry3 = $mysqli->query($query3);
while($f3 = $qry3->fetch_assoc())
{
    $str_html = $str_html."<th>
    Experiencia en Roles de: ".mb_convert_encoding($f3['nombre'],'utf-16','utf-8').
        '</th>';
}
$str_html = $str_html."</tr>";
while($f = $qry->fetch_assoc())
{
    $mail = $f['email'];
    foreach($f as $key=>$value)
    {
        $f[$key] = mb_convert_encoding($value,'utf-16','utf-8');
    }
    $str_html = $str_html."
  <tr>
    <td>
      ".$f['apellido']."
    </td>
    <td>
".$f['nombre']."
    </td>
    <td>
      ".$f['email']."
    </td>
    <td>
".$f['cel']."
    </td>
    <td>
      http://litup.cl/registro/".$f['cv']."
    </td>
    <td>
      http://litup.cl/registro/".$f['foto']."
    </td>";
    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM ind_exp ORDER BY nombre ASC";
    $qry1 = $mysqli->query($query1);
    while($f1 = $qry1->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $str_html = $str_html."<td>";
        $query3 = "SELECT * FROM rel WHERE id_reg = '$mail' AND tipo_rel = 'iec'";
        $qry3 = $mysqli->query($query3);
        //echo $qry3->num_rows;
        //echo $query3;
        while($f3 = $qry3->fetch_assoc())
        {
            //echo $f1['nombre'].' - '.$f3['nombre_ext'];
            if($f1['nombre'] == $f3['nombre_ext'])
            {
                $aux = $f1['nombre'];
                $cosa = mb_convert_encoding($aux,'utf-16','utf-8');
                $str_html = $str_html." ".$cosa." ";
            }
            if($f3['otro']=='si' && $f1['nombre']== 'Otra Industria')
            {
                $aux = $f3['nombre_ext'];
                $cosa = mb_convert_encoding($aux,'utf-16','utf-8');
                $str_html = $str_html." ".$cosa." ";
            }
        }
        //echo 'Industria de apoyo: '.$f1['nombre'];
        $str_html = $str_html."</td>";
    }

    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM proy_exp ORDER BY nombre ASC";
    $qry1 = $mysqli->query($query1);
    while($f1 = $qry1->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $str_html = $str_html."</td>";
        $query3 = "SELECT * FROM rel WHERE id_reg = '$mail' AND tipo_rel = 'pec'";
        $qry3 = $mysqli->query($query3);
        //echo $qry3->num_rows;
        //echo $query3;
        while($f3 = $qry3->fetch_assoc())
        {
            //echo $f1['nombre'].' - '.$f3['nombre_ext'];
            if($f1['nombre'] == $f3['nombre_ext'])
            {
                $aux = $f1['nombre'];
                $cosa = mb_convert_encoding($aux,'utf-16','utf-8');
                $str_html = $str_html." ".$cosa." ";
            }
            if($f3['otro']=='si' && $f1['nombre']== 'Otro Proyecto')
            {
                $aux = $f3['nombre_ext'];
                $cosa = mb_convert_encoding($aux,'utf-16','utf-8');
                $str_html = $str_html." ".$cosa." ";
            }
        }
        //echo 'Industria de apoyo: '.$f1['nombre'];
        $str_html = $str_html."</td>";
    }


    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM rol_exp ORDER BY nombre ASC";
    $qry1 = $mysqli->query($query1);
    while($f1 = $qry1->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $str_html = $str_html."</td>";
        $query3 = "SELECT * FROM rel WHERE id_reg = '$mail' AND tipo_rel = 'rec'";
        $qry3 = $mysqli->query($query3);
        //echo $qry3->num_rows;
        //echo $query3;
        while($f3 = $qry3->fetch_assoc())
        {
            //echo $f1['nombre'].' - '.$f3['nombre_ext'];
            if($f1['nombre'] == $f3['nombre_ext'])
            {
                $aux = $f1['nombre'];
                $cosa = mb_convert_encoding($aux,'utf-16','utf-8');
                $str_html = $str_html." ".$cosa." ";
            }
        }
        //echo 'Industria de apoyo: '.$f1['nombre'];
        $str_html = $str_html."</td>";
    }
    $str_html = $str_html."</tr>";
}
$str_html = $str_html."</table></body>";
//echo $mysqli->error;
echo $str_html;

//Save File
$today = date('j-m-y'); 
file_put_contents('./cxls/consultores'.$today.'.html', $str_html);

/** Include PHPExcel */
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Classes/PHPExcel.php';

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('HTML');
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load('./cxls/consultores'.$today.'.html');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('./cxls/consultores'.$today.'.xlsx');

?>
```

Hope can you help me.

Comment: Why are you converting from UTF-8 to UTF-16 before storing the value in the markup? PHPExcel works with UTF-8, and you have nothing in your markup to say that you're using UTF-16.... stick to UTF-8

Comment: Thank you Mark, this resolve the issue, I actually remove the whole convert encoding.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Mark in the comments, my issue was the UTF-16, I completely remove the `mb_convert_encoding($string,'utf-16','utf-8');` and everything is working.